# Как сделать, чтобы код js исполнялся только при достижении div'a на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

есть div .invest для которого написан скрипт. как сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнялся только когда пользователь доходит до этого div'a на странице?

Comment: В смысле "доходит" ?
Если дело в курсоре, то все легко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о скролинге страницы, то можно расчитать к примеру таким образом:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('invest');
var sourceBottom = elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset < sourceBottom) {
        alert("Вижу див");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = 0,

    //"самописный" селектор выбирает все элементы на экране, между "верхом" и "низом" 
    //(горизонтаьная прокрутка не учитывается, но можно дописать по-аналогии)
    (function(){
        $.belowthefold = function(element) {
            var fold = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
            return fold <= $(element).offset().top;
        };

        $.abovethetop = function(element) {
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            return top >= $(element).offset().top + $(element).height();
        };

        $.inviewport = function(element) {
            return !$.belowthefold(element) && !$.abovethetop(element);
        };

        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
            "inViewport": function(a){return $.inviewport(a);}
        });
    })(),

    handler = function(){
        var inViewportList = $('div:inViewport');  //набор элементов, видимых в окне браузера
        //делайте с ними что хотите
        //ваш код
    };


handler();

//вызывает "handler" с задержкой (500 мс) после "каждого скролла"
//если успел прокрутить дальше, то обрабатывается только "второй скролл" и т.д.
//очень удобно - меньше вычислений - меньше нагрузка на браузер
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(timer){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(handler, 500);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Поместите код скрипта в тэге `<script>...</script>` после нужного вам div'а.

Comment: Думаю, что после

Comment: Извиняюсь, после.

Comment: Плохой совет. В таком случае этот скрипт вызовется в тот момент, когда div будет загружен браузером, **но не** когда пользователь дойдёт до него.

Comment: Тогда скрипт не выполняется вообще.

Comment: А что значит пользователь дойдет до него?

Comment: @MaksimKlimenko, видимо что-то со скроллом, если доскролилось до объекта - то запускается js

Comment: ну, тогда событие onscroll обрабатывать надо.